# Formatting for having one noun used twice in a sentence-- once, implied

Tags: nouns

I was writing some definitions for a summer project, and I came up with this sentence:

> In The Metamorphosis, by Franz Kafka, the protagonist is Gregor
>   Samsa, with events being centered around- , and the story actually
>   being told by him.

I'm not sure how to format the break between `around` and `, and the...`. In Psuedocode, here is what I want to know how to format-- Specifically, the `{implied him}` part.

> [PNoun is the Noun, with the Noun being Verb(Past) by {Implied him}
>   and the Noun being Verb(Past) by him.]

ALSO:
`I am doing the thing - You know the one - without it.` " - " or "-"?
`I am doing the thing-- without it.` "-- " or "--" or " -- "?

Comment: However you punctuate it, I find this to be at best "ungainly" phrasing. If I try to *read it out aloud*, things start to fall apart when I have to consider exactly how to "stress" the eventual and long-overdue appearance of the word ***him***.

Comment: For your first sample sentence I would suggest either no punctuation at all between *around* and *and,* or a comma, or a dash, or a left-hand banana "("--and whatever you choose, put the same thing between *by* and *him* at the end, except if you go with bananas use a right-hand one there. Since thus isolating a mere "him" at the end is a bit goofy, the no-punctuation option works best. But @FumbleFingers is right: it is ungainly even so. Apart from that, the sentence is simply untrue: "The Metamorphosis" does not employ a first-person P.O.V.

Comment: As for dashes used to demarcate parenthetical material, use the long or em dash (html "&mdash;") without space at either end, or the shorter en dash ("&ndash;") *with* space at either end. I *think* the former is more US (Chicago Manual Style specifically enjoins it), the latter UK. Your word processor may well take care of it for you: type two hyphens with no space and it should automatically convert to unspaced em dash (when you finish typing the following word and hit the space bar or a punctuation key); or type space-hyphen-space and it should automatically convert to spaced en dash.

Comment: Why come up with only one sentence? And why all the passives? If you're dealing with literature, you should be exemplifying clear style, e.g, _The protagonist in "The Metamorphosis", by Franz Kafka, is Gregor Samsa. He tells the story, and the events in the story center around him._ Complicated ellipses make for complicated reading and should not be encouraged in students.

Comment: What John Lawler and FumbleFingers say. As a rule of thumb: if Great Mother English makes it difficult to do things the way you're trying to do them, it's a clear sign that She doesn't like the way you're trying to do them. Find another way.

Comment: Per http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4722, please ‘never’ use   or ˋbackticksˋ on ELU. Per http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/364 for the use–mention distinction, please use an italic face.

Comment: You could use an even simpler sentence:

The events of Franz Kafka's short story "The Metamorphosis" are centered around its protagonist and narrator, Gregor Samsa.

Comment: Beautifully constructed sentences are like modern art. If you can still say it clearly, the lesser, the better. Not only did the sentence sound fine, it was well crafted. I'm in love with economy. It makes me want more. If you really do it well, it's like pulling a rabbit. How is it possible to be so concise with so few words? Yeah, that's the ticket.

Comment: I may not have read the other comments carefully but the sentence is fine, with **one comma more**: "In The Metamorphosis, by Franz Kafka, the protagonist is Gregor Samsa, with events being centered around, and the story actually being told **by, him**." However, we do not take so much trouble to factor just one word *him* -- use this technique to factor a longer clause.

Comment: I'm unhappy about it being stated that a story is centred around its protagonist.

Answer (score 1):

### Prologue

1. It seems this question was [necroed](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Necroing) because it was all comments
   and no answers.
2. @BrianDonovan is correct, but since this forum is about usage and not facts, I will ignore that issue.
3. As nearly all commentators stated, the sentence itself is sub-par, but since this is a forum about grammar and not pretty prose, I will ignore those issues, too.

### Answers from the comments

All of the following are grammatically correct in [American English](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/223552/is-it-acceptable-to-use-a-single-hyphen-as-a-dash-as-the-bbc-does).

1. In *The Metamorphosis*, by Franz Kafka, the protagonist is Gregor Samsa, with events being centered around, and the story actually being told, by him.
2. In *The Metamorphosis*, by Franz Kafka, the protagonist is Gregor Samsa, with events being centered around—and the story actually being told—by him.
3. In *The Metamorphosis*, by Franz Kafka, the protagonist is Gregor Samsa, with events being centered around (and the story actually being told) by him.

### Coda

Many conundrums in English writing can be solved by recasting the sentence using preferred styles. Two of the suggestions in the comments are excellent places to start: strongly prefer the [active voice](http://www.towson.edu/ows/activepass.htm), and when faced with punctuation problems divide into multiple sentences.

Comment: Good answer. But in your summary you didn't mention two of the effective techniques you used in your examples: setting off parenthetical phrase with em-dashes, and setting them off with parentheses. Either of these fixes the sentence very nicely without "breaking into two" (which you suggest, but don't illustrate.)

Comment: Thank you. True, both of those are buried in the comments above, but I could have explained them instead of just illustrating. Oh, well.